# How to disable access - request to standard MVC Controller with Bearer token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I have simple Cookie and Bearer Token authorization in my MVC project with WebApi. I want to disable access by Bearer on my standard MVC controllers.

This is my situation now:

- *Standard MVC controllers access*: **Bearer** or **Cookie**
- *Web Api controllers access*: **only Bearer**

I want to have:

- *Standard MVC controllers access*: **only Cookie**
- *Web Api controllers access*: **only Bearer**

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter("Bearer"));
    }
}
```

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthBearerOptions { get; private set; }
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
}
```

Is it possible to have custom authorization attribute? Like this: **[Authorize("OnlyCookie"]**

I saw similar solution, but it was for SinglePageAplication, and I dont know how to implement it in my .NET MVC 4 application - I saw it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme

When I tried add '**AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie"**', compilator gives me error: **CookieAuthenticationOptions' does not contain a definition for 'AuthenticationScheme**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't that property because you're not using ASP.Net Core. The link you post on your question is ASP.Net Core not ASP.NEt MVC.

You can do the same by creating a custom authorization filter attribute. Let name it `CustomAuthorizeAttribute` and the implementation will be:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string AuthenticationType { get; private set; }

    public CustomAuthorize(string authenticationType)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authenticationType))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(authenticationType));
        }

        this.AuthenticationType = authenticationType;
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (!httpContext.User.Identity.AuthenticationType.Equals(this.AuthenticationType, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

So you can use it like this on your controller:

```
[CustomAuthorize(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)]
```